# Block users from editing JSON objects from response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, security

I'm developing a JEE application with AngularJS. This app is meant to be secure, so I was wondering if there's a way to block a user from editing a JSON coming form a response, or a variable in the controller, if he goes into the debugger console in Chrome/Firefox.

For instance: I store the resulting ID of an LDAP authentication in my AngularJS controller. If the user opens the Dev Console in Chrome and puts a breakpoint in the line right after this variable is assigned, they'll be able to modify it, as far as I know.

Is there a way to make my controller safe from this kind of tampering?

Comment: The user can also make a request directly to your URL *without* using your app.

Answer (score 1):

In front-end world, everything could be changed by users. You cannot rely on front-end code to guarantee the security. If your app requires high security, you should have your backend server validates the posted data.